# "AddNew cannot be called on the 'System.Int32' type"

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I have a `BindingNavigator` feeding data to a `DataGrid` and the "add new" button was disabled despite me going into the properties window in the designer and enabling it.

So I force it to be enabled inside the code. I click on it bring up a new add form via `ShowDialog`. Upon exiting the add form a sub runs to refresh the data. I then get this error :

> AddNew cannot be called on the 'System.Int32' type. This type does not
>   have a public default constructor. You can call AddNew on the
>   'System.Int32' type if you set AllowNew=true and handle the AddingNew
>   event.

at this line inside Main

```
Application.Run(new Form1());

    private void PopulateForm()
    {
        totalRecords = fm.GetPPT_Count();

        PageOffsetList po = new PageOffsetList();
        po.totalRecords = totalRecords;
        vwFoodProdProdTextBindingSource.DataSource = po;

        if(bindingNavigator1.AddNewItem.Enabled == false)
        {
            bindingNavigator1.AddNewItem.Enabled = true;
        }           
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Enabled is readonly if I recall correctly. If you want to set the AddNewItem try looking for a IsEnabled property it should be read/write.

Comment: I don't see an "IsEnabled" property in intellisense or anywhere